# In C# 7.2, can I use `in` arguments in delegates, interfaces, or abstract classes?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-7.2

I noticed that when building an interface, a delegate, or an abstract method with an `in` argument, I get a compiler error (CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute' is not defined or imported).  The error message is not very instructive to me.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this not supported?  Unless I'm misreading it, the documentation suggests that should work:

> The in modifier may be applied to any member that takes parameters: methods, delegates, lambdas, local functions, indexers, operators.

See below for an example:

```
public class Parser
{
    // Works
    public bool Parse(in ReadOnlySpan<char> span) => false;
}

public interface IParser
{
    // CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute' is not defined or imported
    bool Parse(in ReadOnlySpan<char> span);
}

public abstract class AbstractParser
{
    // CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute' is not defined or imported
    public abstract bool Parse(in ReadOnlySpan<char> span);
}

// CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute' is not defined or imported
public delegate bool ParseDelegate(in ReadOnlySpan<char> span);
```

This is in a .NET Core 2 App, in Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.3), and I do have `<LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>` in my project file.

---

**Update:**

This appears to be tied to a Nuget package that was in the project.  If I remove the package reference to `Sigil 4.7.0`, the build works.

Also, if I re-install Sigil AND install `System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.3.0` package, the build works then too.

I'm happy that this can work, but what's going here?

Comment: You could try adding the System.Runtime.InteropServices nuget package to the project.  It however certainly should not be necessary, it is included by default.

Comment: I have no issues with the code provided in LINQPad, or dropped into a fresh asp.net core project (once language level is set to 7.2). There's something going on with either your project or your environment.

Comment: I just compiled your code with .net core 2.1 (sorry don't have 2.0 installed) in visual studio code and got zero warnings.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a .Net Core 2.0 application (after adding a package reference to `System.Memory` for `ReadOnlySpan`). Can you share your whole csproj file? Also, are you getting any other warnings or errors?

Comment: So it turns out it's being (somehow) caused by a Nuget package installed in the project (Sigil 4.7.0).  I forgot I'd installed that in anticipation of work I was doing. I'm not totally clear on why this package is causing this particular problem, though, and only in these specific instances.

Comment: That is a pretty tricky library, don't assume it has been tested well on recent .netcore versions.  Created by an SO employee btw.  Best way to get ahead is by clicking the [New Isssue button](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Sigil/issues).  But keep in mind that Kevin is probably waiting for your bug fix submission.